# Is it possible to make Certificates in Latex?

Tags: cross-referencing

I've been learning how to write documents in Latex and recently I was wondering whether the TEX editor can be used to make elegant looking Certificates. If it is possible that please suggest templates or references from where I can gather the tools to make a certificate in LATEX.